# Aws lambda cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda that consumes data from another AWS account's Athena. So I have a role that my lambda assumes which have cross-account access. I had used STS client in my lambda. sometimes lambda is running perfectly fine and sometimes it breaks and gives me this error.

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The security token included in the request is expired",
>         "errorType": "ClientError",

STS client i used in my code is :

```
def assume_role_to_session(role_arn, session_name):
client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName=session_name, DurationSeconds=900)
return boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
    region_name='us-east-1')
assume_role_athena_session = assume_role_to_session(role_arn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/role-name',
                                    session_name='AthenaLambdaSession')
```

How does this work? I want my lambda to run anytime not just sometimes. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this document](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html)

> RoleSessionName (string) -- [REQUIRED]
>
> **An identifier for the assumed role session**.
>
> Use the role session name to **uniquely identify a session** when the same
>   role is assumed by different principals or for different reasons. In
>   cross-account scenarios, the role session name is visible to, and can
>   be logged by the account that owns the role. The role session name is
>   also used in the ARN of the assumed role principal. This means that
>   subsequent cross-account API requests using the temporary security
>   credentials will expose the role session name to the external account
>   in their CloudTrail logs.

So try to replace `AthenaLambdaSession` with **unique RoleSessionName**. Or if you want to reuse existing session, try to check session timeout to make sure that enough time to execute your lambda task (max 5 minutes). If < 5 minutes, re-new it.